# custom Membership fields disappearing?

Tags: asp.net-membership, sitecore, sitecore6

I have added a custom profile field named 'Relatiecode' to my user profile according to the SDN developer guide. I have entered a value via the sitecore User Manager. More specifically, I set it to '0000008' for the user extranet\coordinator8, and 0000001 for the user extranet\coordinator1, like this:

[image: the data is right there in user manager]

I have verified that this is also stored in the sql database
[image: the data is right there in sql]

however, when I attempt to access the data in my asp.Net webform (sublayout, actually), the field appears to be empty for user 'coordinator8'. What really confuses me is that it seems to be working perfectly for user 'coordinator1'. See below:

[image: confused]

I'm at a loss! What am I doing wrong? Thoughts?

sitecore version 6.5

Comment: Just out of curiosity if you reverse the order of the users is the property of user1 empty?

Comment: good question - at this point I'm kind of desperate, so I'll take anything, including debugging tips ;) - by order, you mean the order in the database, or the order of the membership calls (lines 40, 43)? I'm assuming the latter. Will check tomorrow.

Comment: nope, doesn't make a difference :(

Comment: can you try getting any other property for coordinate8 user? Also make sure that the user has correct domain and there are no typos. Your codes seems to be correct.

Comment: @Stephan, are there any errors in the log? Have you tried the above suggestion to get any other property? What if you drop and recreate the 'coordinator8'? Otherwise, it seems to be a good candidate to contact Sitecore Support with...

Comment: @naveed_ahmad - I have tried this, but no luck

Comment: @Yan -tried that as well, coordinator8 is just an example but I have the same problem with other users. "coordinator1" is the only one which actually works.

Comment: @Stefan, I would still strongly recommend you contacting Sitecore Support with this problem - it might indicate a tricky bug, and you have a great chance to help digging it out!

Answer (score 0):

Not *the* solution, but because of deadlines I decided to go with a makeshift solution... we're storing the fields in a custom SQL database now, and querying it with NHibernate.